# how to use [left] [Right] to split comma separated values more than 2?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

```
A1= 831  , 12673 , 12286 , 5974
```

`=LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1,1) - 1))` it returns 831 thats OK.

If, `=Right(A1,FIND(",",A1,1) - 1))` returns 5974

But how to get middle 2 values like 12673 & 12286 ??

Note- My values do not have fixed length, some of them are 4 digit, some 3 and some 5.

Comment: Have you tried `SPLIT` function?

Comment: No. Can you give me a demo plz?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `B1`, enter `=SPLIT(A1,",")`. This will split the comma separated value in A1 into 831, 12673, 12286, 5974.

You can play around with the function to include spaces too.

Comment: Where do you get the SPLIT function from?  My excel (2010), doesn't seem to recognise it.

Comment: @orangesherbert - I believe the question was for google spreadsheet which have a [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en) function.